# why I have NAN after key-value matching with dict in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add new label column by key-value matching with a dictionary in my dataframe. I used `map` function to do so. But, the value of new added column all have `NAN`, means that matching doesn't work in my code. How can I correct this? why is that happening? I intend to add new label column by matching key from my dictionary to key in pandas dataframe.

**minimal data**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[list('EEEIEEIIEI'), 
          ['AR', 'AUC', 'CA', 'CN', 'MX', 'MX', 'AR', 'IT', 'UK', 'RU'],
          ['ALBANIA', 'PAKISTN', 'UGANDA', 'FRANCE', 'USA', 'RUSSIA', 'COLOMBIA', 'KAZAK', 'KOREA', 'JAPAN'],
          [20230, 20220, 20120, 20230, 20230, 20220, 20230, 20120, 20130, 20329],
          list(np.random.randint(10, 100, 10)),
          list(np.random.randint(10, 100, 10))]
          ).T


df.columns =['ID', 'cty', 'cty_ptn', 'prod_code', 'Quantity1', 'Quantity2']
print(df)
```

here is my code:

```
my_dict={'20230':'Gas',
        '20220':'Water',
        '20210': 'Refined',
        '20120':'Oil',
        '20239':'Other'}

df['prod_label']=df['prod_code'].map(my_dict)
```

how can I fix `NAN` in new assigned column? any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the column `prod_code` is a `int` you have to convert to `str` with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) before mapping:

```
my_dict={'20230':'Gas',
    '20220':'Water',
    '20210': 'Refined',
    '20120':'Oil',
    '20239':'Other'}

df['prod_label']=df['prod_code'].astype(str).map(my_dict)
```

---

```
  ID  cty   cty_ptn prod_code Quantity1 Quantity2 prod_label
0  E   AR   ALBANIA     20230        45        84        Gas
1  E  AUC   PAKISTN     20220        68        10      Water
2  E   CA    UGANDA     20120        48        45        Oil
3  I   CN    FRANCE     20230        11        93        Gas
4  E   MX       USA     20230        62        81        Gas
5  E   MX    RUSSIA     20220        27        49      Water
6  I   AR  COLOMBIA     20230        55        97        Gas
7  I   IT     KAZAK     20120        32        93        Oil
8  E   UK     KOREA     20130        63        88        NaN
9  I   RU     JAPAN     20329        99        39        NaN
```